# returns a list of indices in common given two compressed vectors

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example,

```
d1 == {'inds': [9, 9, 1, 9, 8, 1], 
       'vals': [0.28, 0.84, 0.71, 0.03, 0.04, 0.75]}

d2 == {'inds': [0, 9, 9, 1, 3, 3, 9], 
       'vals': [0.26, 0.06, 0.46, 0.58, 0.42, 0.21, 0.53, 0.76]}
```

how to return the common index by a function below?

```
find_common_inds(d1, d2) == [1, 9]
```

here is my code but it seems not working

```
intersect = []
for key in d1.keys():
    if key in d2.keys():
           intersect.append(key)
print(intersect)
```

Comment: You would probably have more luck getting an answer if you provided some explanation about your data structure and how you are supposed to derive the output from your inputs.

Comment: Does your *common index* means common elements of 2 lists `inds` in `d1` and `d2`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use set intersection on flattened list of values:

```
from itertools import chain

d1 = {'inds': [9, 9, 1, 9, 8, 1], 'vals': [0.28, 0.84, 0.71, 0.03, 0.04, 0.75]}

d2 = {'inds': [0, 9, 9, 1, 3, 3, 9], 'vals': [0.26, 0.06, 0.46, 0.58, 0.42, 0.21, 0.53, 0.76]}

print(set(chain.from_iterable(d1.values())).intersection(chain.from_iterable(d2.values())))
# {9, 1}
```

**References**:

- [set.intersection()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection).
- Flattening lists using [chain.from_iterable()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to:

```
def find_common_values_in_identical_keys(d1,d2,**kwargs):
    if 'keyname' in kwargs: 
        kn = kwargs['keyname']   # this is hard  :P and it would still allow a "key"
                                 # that's not a hashable so it will crash donw below :/
    if kn: 
        try:
            return list(set(d1.get(kn, set())).intersection(d2.get(kn, [])))
        except TypeError as e:
            print("Bad keyname:", e)
    else:
        return [(k,find_common_values_in_identical_keys(d1,d2,keyname = k)) 
                for k in set(d1.keys()).union(d2)]  



d1 = {'inds': [9, 9, 1, 9, 8, 1], 
      'vals': [0.28, 0.84, 0.71, 0.03, 0.04, 0.75]}

d2 = {'inds': [0, 9, 9, 1, 3, 3, 9], 
      'vals': [0.26, 0.06, 0.46, 0.58, 0.42, 0.21, 0.53, 0.76]}


print(find_common_values_in_identical_keys(d1,d2,"inds"))
```

wich then prints:

```
[9,1] # the order is random as sets are inheritently unordered
```

This also handles the case for *all* keys:

```
print(find_common_values_in_identical_keys(d1,d2))
```

Output:

```
[('vals', []), ('inds', [9, 1])]
```

returning a list of tuples of (keyname, [list of identical values])

---

You might still want to guard against `d1` & `d2` being not `dict`ionaries using `isinstance(...)` and throwing `ValueError`s to make it more foolproof.

Comment: You've got some stuff converting to sets here unnecessarily... `df1.keys() | df2.keys() ` will give you a set back without the explicit conversions... and where you have a keyname you can use: `list(set(d1.get(keyname, set())).intersection(d2.get(keyname, []))`... as `.intersection` can take any iterable

Comment: One other thing to consider is the `if keyname` check... empty strings, numbers equalling zero and indeed `None` itself are valid keys in a dictionary (albeit it not necessarily common) - so you might want to consider a sentinel value there so you can work with `None`/0/`''` etc... if necessary...

Comment: @JonClements sentinel ... wouldn't  `if keyname in d1 or keyname in d2:` solve that? The `keyname=None` would then only work as sugar to enable calling the func with only 1 param ... wouldn't look for someone putting a None as key - 0 though is very likely as might empty strings - all being Falsy.

Comment: Probably a simple change is to make it `**kwargs` and then check `if 'keyname' in kwargs`...

Comment: Not quite... you want `if 'keyname' in kwargs: kn = kwargs['keyname']; return list(set(...))` else you'll still miss cases where the key happens to be a falsy value. (The current change is no different than default `keyname=None` itself...)